# Qt button display abnormal

Tags: qt

I just installed Qt and planned to create an example using QML. The program was generated using a wizard, but I added some buttons to it. To make it clear, this time I added a few more buttons, but the resulting layout is not something I can comprehend. The layout I can understand should look like the one above, but what was generated is shown below. Qt is newly installed, and I haven't configured anything yet.

**Expected:**
[image: normal]

**Actual:**
[image: abnormal]

I just started learning Qt QML. The version of Qt Creator I'm using is 11.0, built with Qt 6.5.2 for Mac. I believe that standard controls should have default properties, and they should appear in a normal state, not completely invisible like this. Do I need to set default properties first in Qt 6.5.2 before I can start programming?

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button
    {
        x: 105
        y: 55
        width: 104
        height: 52
        visible: true
        text: qsTr("Hello Button")
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 105
        y: 152
        width: 110
        height: 42
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    Button {
        id: button1
        x: 253
        y: 161
        width: 104
        height: 41
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    Button {
        id: button2
        x: 255
        y: 60
        width: 131
        height: 65
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    Button {
        x: 102
        y: 250
        width: 104
        height: 52
        visible: true
        text: qsTr("Hello Button")
    }

    Button {
        id: button3
        x: 102
        y: 347
        width: 110
        height: 42
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    Button {
        id: button4
        x: 250
        y: 356
        width: 104
        height: 41
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    Button {
        id: button5
        x: 252
        y: 255
        width: 131
        height: 65
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: There are no errors at all. Even though I am a beginner in QML, I have been working with GUI programming for a long time, so I can usually troubleshoot common errors. Currently, there are no errors, so I am wondering if QML programming requires any specific setup

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some reasons that you can check:

- The button may be synced with your Macbook system-style theme.
- You configured it in the qtquickcontrols2.conf file with the white color for text

You can check [Styling Qt Quick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls), and [Qt Quick Controls Configuration File](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html) for more info.

Hope this answer can help you resolve it